# How to deal with negative exponents in modular arithmetic?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, cryptography

So I think I understand how to calculate something like $(208\cdot 2^{-1})\mod 421$ using extended euclidean algorithm. But how would you calculate something like $(208\cdot2^{-21})\mod 421$?

Thanks, this is basically for my cryptography class; I'm just trying to understand the "big step, baby step" algorithm.

Comment: You're solving for the inverse. What times 208*2^21 mod 421 is equal to 1?

Answer (score 4):

Remember that one of the rules of exponents is that
$$(x^a)^b = x^{ab}.$$
So we can rewrite 
$$208 \cdot 2^{-21} \pmod{421}$$ 
as 
$$208 \cdot (2^{-1})^{21} \pmod{421}.$$
You can then solve for the modular multiplcative inverse by [one of a few techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Computation), including, as you note, the *Extended Euclidean Algorithm*. With this specific example, we get
$$x \equiv 208 \cdot (2^{-1})^{21} \pmod{421}$$
$$\equiv 208 \cdot (211)^{21} \pmod{421}$$
$$\equiv 208 \cdot 329 \pmod{421}$$
$$\equiv 230 \pmod{421}$$

Comment: So is 211 the modulo muliplicative inverse of 2^-1?